# Does macOS 10.13.4 display 32-bit warnings like the beta versions do?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, 32-bit, beta

The beta versions of macOS 10.3.4 [were reported](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/01/24/macos-high-sierra-10-13-4-beta/) to include warnings when you started a 32-bit app. From the release notes:

> To prepare for a future release of macOS in which 32-bit software will no longer run without compromise, starting in macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 a user is notified on the launch of an app that depends on 32-bit software.

I've been using the released version of 10.3.4 for a few days, but I haven't seen any notices when I run 32-bit software. Was this feature removed? Or are there special conditions that need to happen before it appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, after midnight, April 12, 2018 in the user's local time zone

From Ars Technica's "[Apple has begun notifying macOS users of coming 32-bit app incompatibility](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/04/apple-has-begun-notifying-macos-users-of-coming-32-bit-app-incompatibility/)".

> Starting at midnight April 12, 2018 in the user's local time zone, they will see the following message the first time they launch an app that only supports 32-bit in macOS High Sierra 10.13.4:
>
> > This app needs to be updated by its developer to improve compatibility.
>
> Along with that message, they'll see a "learn more" link that takes them to [Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436) on the subject with more information. The support page broadly explains Apple's plans to "eventually" require all Mac software to be 64-bit.

[image: macOS 10.3.4 32-bit app warning]